# Squeeze the label if there is no data in Lita

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

On the screen I have a label called `namelabel` and `agelabel`. `namelabel` is set above the `agelabel`. These two labels' datas are taken from Lita with sqlite. What I want to do is, if there is no name data in Lita, I would like to move the `agelabel` to the namelabel's position. I have wrote the following code, but it did not work. 
//Lita's data table's name is "table".

```
    if(table.age == nil) {
    UILabel *agelabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(20,350,100,30)];
    agelabel.text = table.age;
    [self.view addSubview:agelabel];

    } else {
    UILabel *namelabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(20,350,100,30)];
    namelabel.text = table.name;
    [self.view addSubview:namelabel];
    UILabel *agelabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(20,370,100,30)];
    agelabel.text = table.age;
    [self.view addSubview:agelabel];
    }
```

Please help me with dealing this question.
Thank you very much.

Comment: did it show NSNull? maybe you need to check for @"" or [NSNull null]

Comment: Yes, I have tried it. However, even when the data is not in the table, the second condition was applied all the time.

Comment: You can try to debug it using NSLog(%@,NSStringFromClass([table.age class]))

Answer (score 0):

I solved this question by writing it as below:

```
if ([table.age length] == 0){}
```